# iOS4.2 and iOS4.1 on the same machine?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I'd like to start testing iOS4.2 so I downloaded xcode 3.2.5 and iOS4.2 beta SDK. Unfortunately, I think it installed over my previous xcode 3.2.4 and SDK 4.1. Short of downloading 3.2.4 and 4.1 and installing to another directory, is there a way to get the 4.1 SDK into 3.2.5 and compile both SDK versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like with the release of iOS 4.2, Apple is going to want 4.2 to reign king. At least with Xcode 3.2.5 GM, the only SDK included is 4.2.

You can have two versions of Xcode installed though - when choosing what optional things you want to uninstall, uncheck everything and change the location Xcode installs to (it defaults to /Developer). I was able to get 3.2.5 (can compile against 4.2) and 3.2.4 (everything else) running and working on the same machine. This will allow you to have both the 4.2 and 4.1 SDKs on the same machine.

Good luck!